# how to create hashcode and equals for optional parameters

Tags: java, json, guava, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I want to create a RESTful web service. I have a User Class. I want to create multiple User objects and store it in a hashmap to mock a database. So when a client sends a PUT request, based on the JSON data, and extracting ID from JSON, I can perform operations in the hashmap to update or remove. Is the following a proper way to override equals and hashcode method. But the question is what happens if the zip or the middlename is null or empty. The ID will be incremented in the constructor everytime an object is created.

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final AtomicInteger ID = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private String firstName;
    private Optional<String> middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private Gender gender;
    private String phone;
    private Optional<String> zip;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final User other = (User) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.ID, other.ID)
                &&  Objects.equals(this.firstName, other.firstName)
                && Objects.equals(this.middleName, other.middleName)
                && Objects.equals(this.lastName, other.lastName)
                && Objects.equals(this.age, other.age)
                && Objects.equals(this.gender, other.gender)
                && Objects.equals(this.phone, other.phone)
                && Objects.equals(this.zip, other.zip);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(
                this.firstName, this.middleName, this.lastName, this.age, this.gender, this.phone, this.zip);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("firstName", this.firstName)
                .add("middleName", this.middleName)
                .add("lastName", this.lastName)
                .add("age", this.age)
                .add("gender", this.gender)
                .add("phone", this.phone)
                .add("zip", this.zip)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the ID being incremented anywhere

Comment: "If the zip or the middlename is null or empty" Well, you're using `Optional` -  so it should never be null - that defeats the point of using `Optional` in the first place. If it's empty, that's no different to if it is non-empty. The behaviour of `Optional.equals` and `Optional.hashCode` with respect to present or absent values are described in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#hashCode--).

Comment: But if you actually *do* have null values, then `Objects.equals` and `Objects.hash` handle those.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi the id will be incremented, as i will be using builder pattern to initialize the user object and in the private User constructor increment the ID.

Comment: @shawnderik So you talking about a problem in code that is not here?

Comment: `Objects.equals(this.ID, other.ID)` is misleading. `ID` is static so there is only one of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Objects.equals(this.middleName.orElse(null), other.middleName.orElse(null))
```